# numerical evaluation of infinite series super divergent

Tags: calculus

I like to sum the following series
$$\text{Sum}\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k (-x)^k,\{k,0,\infty \},\text{Regularization}\to \text{Borel}\right]\text{/.}\, x\to 1$$ the result is $$e \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$$ and aproximately gives 0.757872
but things normaly do not so easy and I want to sum
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k}{\cos (k+2)}$$ but Mathematia say does not converge and maple do not gives any  result but  I think the result is about -5.15302890 it is possible to get some method to sum this type of sum??
the same question for the following serie
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k}{\zeta (k+2)^6}\approx 0.206033$$